# Converting from Binary to Decimal without using arithmetic operations

Tags: c, binary, ieee-754, 16-bit

I had this written until i realized * is an arithmetic operation.

I want to return a nonnegative integer representation of the binary sequence input. IE. 0x4a returns 74 in decimal

```
typedef unsigned bit16;

unsigned int bin_to_dec(bit16 x)
{
int dec=0;
int k=0;
int remainder;

while (x!= 0){
    remainder = x%10;
    dec+=remainder*k;
    k=k+2;
    x=x/10;
}
```

:(

How would I go about this conversion if I can't use arithmetic operations other than +/-?

Comment: You missed %, + and / which are also arithmetic operations. But why?

Comment: If your function is to return an `int`, then in what sense do you expect that value to be decimal rather than binary?

Comment: You should double-check your requirements. You may be expected to produce a string or array of digit characters, rather than an int. As for the conversion, you could do it with shifts and masks, though it's tricky for base 10 (not being a power of 2).

Comment: @gnasher729 forgot to include that +/- is allowed but the others are not. 

John I want to convert from binary to decimal, which is an int if I'm not mistaken (If im following you correctly here)

Comment: Please show the definition of `bit16`.

Comment: What's `bit16` type? Wouldn't `dec=x` do what you want?

Comment: Update: Yes, it definitely will. A classical confusion of beginners.

Comment: @Code_Penguin, an `int` is no more decimal than any other arithmetic type, which apparently includes `bit16`.  C defines the representations of integral types in terms of a collection of bits.

Comment: Please remove the `IEEE` tag.

Comment: This is either an X-Y question, or misunderstood premise.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's neither. It's a misunderstood concept.

Comment: k is not initialized

Comment: I've updated with some more details, perhaps now it'll be more clear. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Define "integer representation".  Do you mean a character string containing a sequence of decimal digits?  If not, then what?

Comment: @Code_Penguin `0x4A` *is* `74`. They denote absolutely the same literals in C. Try to `printf` your `bit16` and you will see.

Comment: @Code_Penguin, the confusion is all yours.  The premise of the question is mistaken.

Comment: Also, `0x4A` is not a *binary* representation.  It is hexadecimal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. even the high-rep John Bollinger uses the word "premise".

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, our reps are not for linguistics :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. no they are for ideas and mine was (were?) not wrong.

Comment: Voting to close.  The question is utterly ill-defined.  The desired return value has not been specified.  How is the decimal representation meant to be encoded?  As a string?  Packed into an integer with no convenient way to decode it?

Comment: @TomKarzes the OP mentioned + and  - can be used and I think it's not I'll defined

Comment: @CherubimAnand It has nothing to do with the restrictions on which operators can be used.  Read my comments.  It has to do with what the output is.  One more time:  Is it supposed to be a character string?  If not, then what in the world does "base 10" mean in the context of an integer?  Look at OP's example:  If 0x4a is passed as the argument, then 74 should be returned.  But they're *the same number*.  So just `return x;` is all that's needed.  It makes no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As + and - are allowed...Instead of multiplying into `k*reamainder` try looping this way

```
int n;//consider new int
```

In the while loop write first line as

```
n=remainder;
```

Instead of *

```
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    remainder+=n;
```

This would do the multiplication :).

And for x%10, construct a function

```
int mod(int n)
{
   int m;
   while(n>0)
   {
      n=n-10;
      m=n;
    }
   return m;
}
```

And for x/10 it'd be the same but you must return number of times you subtracted like this :

```
int mod(int n)
{
   int count=0;
   while(n>0)
   {
      count=count+1;
      n=n-10;
   }
   return count;
}
```

edit : If + and - are also not allowed try making functions for them using binary operators and use them instead of + and - in the above answer!

Comment: Ignoring for the moment the question's mistaken premise, why do you suppose the `+` part of `+=` would be permitted if arithmetic operations are to be avoided?

Comment: +/- are permitted, they're the only exceptions in the question

Comment: Didn't Op mention in the last line than he can use + / and - @JohnBollinger see the last line

Comment: @CherubimAnand, fair enough -- the OP has an odd definition of "arithmetic operation".  Nevertheless, although you provide a way to work around the disallowed multiplication he asks about, there are still the `/` and `%` that he seems to be overlooking.

Comment: Ya I've done the % @JohnBollinger

Comment: Now I've provided for all of them @JohnBollinger

Comment: I do think this is entirely missing the point, but I lifted my DV.

Comment: Ya fixed it @RolandIllig thanks for mention

Comment: @RolandIllig ya i was doing it but we had a power cut :(... Fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `+` is also an arithmetic operation, it becomes difficult. Depending on the exact rules, using a lookup table might be acceptable: `return lookuptable[x];`

Comment: You could use a really large switch statement :-)

Comment: And in what sense is the returned **`int`** decimal if the input is to be considered non-decimal?

Comment: I don't think it's difficult... If OP could write down functions for + and - using binary operators and rest in the way I've using those functions to add and subtract... I think it's not hard